# Объясните каждую строчку кода BubbleSort?

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Вы можете прокоментировать подробно этот код пузырьковой сортировки. Объяснить каждую строчку, я очень хочу понять этот-то, если есть более современный вариант этого кода, буду рад увидеть, более красивый раскоментированный код.

```
using System;

namespace sort
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] BubbleSort(int[] mas)
        {
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.Length - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (mas[j + 1] < mas[j])
                    {
                        temp = mas[j + 1];
                        mas[j + 1] = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return mas;
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] mass = { 12, 7, 8, 1 };
            var rez = BubbleSort(mass);
            foreach(int c in rez)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А именно эта часть кода мне больше интересна для понимание

```
int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.Length - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (mas[j + 1] < mas[j])
                    {
                        temp = mas[j + 1];
                        mas[j + 1] = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return mas;
        }
```

Comment: Почитайте: [Сортировка пузырьком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC). В статье есть псевдокод, который один-в-один повторяет Ваш код. Если с этим кодом что-то непонятно, то лучше уточните что именно. Выберите одну строчку кода, тщательно изучите ее, и задайте по ней конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю вы должны объяснить код

```
int temp; // объявление переменной temp будет использоваться промежуточным буфером для хранения значения
for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length - 1; i++) // объявление mas.Length - 1 повторений цикла с шагом 1 по переменной i
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mas.Length - i - 1; j++) // объявление mas.Length - 1 - i повторений цикла с шагом 1 по переменной j
    {
        if (mas[j + 1] < mas[j]) // сверка элементов [j + 1] и [j] массива mas
        {
            temp = mas[j + 1]; // сохранение в буфер (переменную) temp значение элемента [j + 1] массива mas 
            mas[j + 1] = mas[j]; // замена значения элемента [j + 1] элементом [j] массива mas
            mas[j] = temp; // замена значения элемента [j] массива mas значением temp
        }
    }
}
return mas; // возврат результирующего массива
```

где

```
{ // начало блока
} // конец блока
```

Comment: if(mas[j+1] <mas[j])  а можете по подробнее рассказать, эту часть кода?

Comment: if(mas[j+1] <mas[j]) - если элемент массива [j+1] меньше чем [j] то ... сравнивают два соседних элемента массива и если один меньше другого то далее меняют местами

Comment: Объясните почему в одной части кода mas[j+1] мы ставим +  а в другой части  указываем  массив и переменную mas[j] мы же вроде нечего добавляем а сравниваем

Comment: это индексы массива. массив m из 5 элементов доступ получают так m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4] так вот mas[j+1] <mas[j] это как сравнивать значения mas[2] < mas[1] при когда j равно 1